# Resolving a duplicate primary key on mysql import

Tags: mysql, wordpress, import, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I'm looking to append a comments table from one WordPress site to another. The users are different. When I import the comments from site B to A, I run into a duplicate key issue; comment_id is already taken.

So how can I resolve this and append the table with a simple .sql file? Would I have to take the user information, generate a new user, check for comments made on site B, pull the content and postID, then go back to site A and recreate the comment for the newly created user!?

What a headache! THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your only problem is a duplicate key issue, go to the end of your sql file after 
`ENGINE=MyISAM`
and make it 
`ENGINE=MyISAM AutoIncrement=a nubmer above the last id in the new database`

or

Query database A for the last id then add one and use it on a new insert query.

Example 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `added` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`,`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

The Inserts From My Dump:

```
INSERT INTO `movies` (`title`, `year`, `size`, `added`) VALUES
('[REC] 2', 0, '716688', '2011-09-23'),
('5 Days of War', 0, '1435406', '2012-01-09'),
('[REC]', 0, '1353420800', '2011-11-06');
```

See how i didnt include the `PRIMARY KEY (id)` in my includes, but it will still check against my `UNIQUE KEY` and see if the title exists. Just a little demo that hopefully helps out. If your table already exists on the new database then just skip to the inserts and dont include the primary key and it will be auto set on a new insert to the next available value.

Comment: So going by your first method, say old database ends in primary key 5, and you say ENGINE=MyISAM AutoIncrement=6, the rest of the entries in the new database will be imported as 6, 7, 8 etc?

Comment: correct, when u set the autoincrement it starts at the number specified, where as if u didnt include it it would automatically start at 1 and move forward and thats what causes your error if you are trying to update from a dump. Just dont include the primary_key in the dump's inserts and it should work like a charm. I will edit and post a demo from one of my DB's.